# RegExp for Cyrillic+minimum 3 letters+without numbers and space+non repeatable at the end

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I do have the following `RegExp` in the current web application.

```
function myCyrillicValidator(text){
    return XRegExp("^\\p{Cyrillic}+$").test(text);
}
```

As you can see I use `XRegExp` javasciprt library. Currently, this `regxep` checks if its `cyrillic`. I want to extend it and to check:

- It's Cyrillic
- It's minimum 3 letters
- It doesnt have space
- The last letters doesnt repeat, i.e Gabenn <- is wrong, Moneyy <- is wrong, beucase the last 2 letters are repeating
- First letter is capital

I tried few online `RegExp` tester/builders to build on top of the current rule. But none of them showed me that the current `regexp` is working correctly. But surprisingly, its working in the webapp, but not in the online testers.

`XregxExp` version is 2.0.0 if it does matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
XRegExp("^(?=\\p{Lu})(?!.*(.)\\1$)\\p{Cyrillic}{3,}$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM4agb/2/).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(?=\\p{Lu})` - the first letter must be an uppercase letter
- `(?!.*(.)\\1$)` - the string should not end with 2 identical chars
- `\\p{Cyrillic}{3,}` - the string should only consist of 3 or more Cyrillic letters
- `$` - end of string anchor

```js
function myCyrillicValidator(text){
    return XRegExp("^(?=\\p{Lu})(?!.*(.)\\1$)\\p{Cyrillic}{3,}$").test(text);
}

console.log(myCyrillicValidator("Ва"));    // => false 
console.log(myCyrillicValidator("вася"));  // => false
console.log(myCyrillicValidator("Васяя")); // => false
console.log(myCyrillicValidator("Вася"));  // => true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perfect mate) Thx a lot